# Loitering Strings in HTTPService

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, memory-management, garbage-collection

Scenario,
I have a Linechart that gatehrs data every 1 minute (for dev purposes this has changes to 10x a second - purely to highlight the issues), the data is returned in JSON format

i process the JSON thus

```
private function processResult(event:ResultEvent):void {
data.removeAll();
seriesData.removeAll();

var JSON:JSONDecoder = new JSONDecoder();
var result:Object = JSON.decode(dataProvider.lastResult.toString());

var tmpData:ArrayCollection = result[source] as ArrayCollection;

for(var i = 0; i < tmpData.length; i++) {
    data.addItem(tmpData[i]);
}
}
```

the loitering object is a string, which upon inspection as 0 paths, and content is the JSON that is returned

why is it loitering and gc not picking it up?
how do i clean it up?

Comment: the string that is loitering is the string of line 5 above. the String is the JSON that is returned, so I can only assume the toString() is making it loiter some how (which makes no sense to me)

forcing gc to run (via both the local connection hack and the profiler button) doesnt seem to mop up these strings

Comment: It's not loitering.  The dataProvider is keeping the reference to it in lastResult until the next result swings by.

Comment: No it's not
the number of strings, goes up in the 10's of thousands (the dataProvider is called every 1/10 of a second) and the result is always in the profiler, so it is loitering